# Qt writting to xml: QIODevice::write (QFile, "D:/logs.xml"): device not open

Tags: c++, xml, windows, qt

I am trying to save data to XML file in Qt. Everywhere is told that i need to write such kind of checking:

```
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to open";
}
else
{
    //write to file;
}
```

I always get "failed to open" result. I just cannot find anything about it. If I don't use this checking I get this kind of error: QIODevice::write (QFile, "D:/logs.xml"): device not open. I just don't know what to do. Here is whole code what I was trying to use from tutorial:

```
QDomDocument document;
// Making the root element
QDomElement root = document.createElement("Dorms");

// Adding the root element to the docuemnt
document.appendChild(root);
QFile file;
file.setFileName("D:/logs.xml");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to open";
}
else
{
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << document.toString();
    file.close();
    qDebug() << "Done";
}
```

Does anyone know what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

You use the wrong slashes for Windows.

## Solution

Change

```
file.setFileName("D:/logs.xml");
```

to

```
file.setFileName("D:\logs.xml");
```

Comment: Now it doesn't tell any error, but file is never to be found

Comment: @Seiggailion, do you get "Done" on the output console?

Comment: @Seiggailion, I've just tested this and it works. I get an xml file with content: `<Dorms/>`.

Comment: @Seiggailion, try to refresh the content of drive `D`. Also, since the error is gone, obviously this answer provides the solution and you could mark it as accepted. If you like it, you might as well consider upvoting it. Another piece of advise is to use [QXmlStreamWriter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html) to create xml files.

Comment: i checked everywhere and tried different directories. There is just no file

Comment: @Seiggailion, I suggest you to leave the question as it is, as it is already solved and post a new one about the missing file, with a link to this question. The case is indeed interesting and fixing the missing file will be more challenging than fixing the slashes, so it deserves a separate topic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you don't have access rights for creating files in used directory D:/. Check the url and permissions.

P.S. for me this example is correct

Comment: Is there some special permission setting in Qt or in code? I work with Windows, as long as know I have permission to create files

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact error message by calling `file.errorString()` after `file.open()` failed. My guess, it's probably an access rights error.

Comment: I get this mistake: "No such file or directory".

Comment: Have you tried opening in another disk or directory?